# How to define a path in RSpec and Cucumber

Tags: rspec, cucumber, capybara

I'm reading Rails 3 in Action by Bigg and Katz and its my first time with RSpec, Cucumber and Capybara.

The RSpec team boldly "[took the training wheels off](http://aslakhellesoy.com/)" So I'm stuck following along concepts in the book since RSpect doesn't provide any starter steps like `paths.rb` or `web_steps.rb` anymore.

My Question is how do I make a path, as in a spec that puts capybara on a desired page.

In the book, its told to put the following in paths.rb (provided by RSpec)

```
when /the project page for "([^\"]*)"/
   project_path(Project.find_by_name!($1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [the article you cite](http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off), Aslak points out that he released [cucumber_rails_training_wheels](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails-training-wheels/) to solve exactly this problem for people in precisely your situation. I'd recommend you use that library as you go through Rails 3 in Action, or use an older version of Cucumber that still supports it.

Also, just an FYI, RSpec and Cucumber haven't been the same project for over two years at this point. `web_steps.rb` is related to Cucumber, and has nothing to do with RSpec.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm reading your RSpec book as well~ This could be another question, but If I want to implement a step that puts the user on some `path` then what is the way to do that without using training wheels.

Comment: Take a look at how `web_steps.rb` and `paths.rb` work. If you're still unsure, I'd recommend you join the http://groups.google.com/group/cukes group and get a discussion going there.